# Extjs - How to add space between checkbox and field label?

Tags: extjs

How to add space between checkbox and text (fieldLabel)?

I tried adding `width: 200,` but it's not working

```
var delete = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox', {
        itemId : 'deleteMICR',
        name: 'deleteMICRDataID',
        fieldLabel : 'Delete MICR Data ?' + '<span id = "deleteMICRHelpIconId" ><img src="../static/images/help_icon.png" height="18" class="icon"/></span>',
        hidden : true,
        width: 500,
        listeners: {
            render: function(c) {
              new Ext.ToolTip({
                target: Ext.get('deleteMICRHelpIconId'),
                html: 'This is applicable only XXXXXX'
              });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It depends. You can try `labelWidth`. If that does not suffice, please provide more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`labelWidth`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html#cfg-labelWidth).

Here's the fiddle: [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hm9)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want label to be on the right side of checkbox use 'boxLabel' property.